# How do i know the shaders and opengl version required are in my pc?

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

The following question/answer(s) do not fully cover my question

[How do I determine if my integrated Intel graphics support "Shader Model 3"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121764/how-do-i-determine-if-my-integrated-intel-graphics-support-shader-model-3)

I have a similar PC I am using for internet, but I would like to try gaming (steam-low spec) too. Here is the result of
`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center     
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 400 (BSW)     
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8     
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60     
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8     
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30     
OpenGL context flags: (none)     
OpenGL ES profile version string: 
OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8 
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: 
OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

I added some extra specs from `glxinfo`:

```
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 400 (BSW) (0x22b1)
Version: 20.0.8
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 1536MB
Unified memory: yes
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 4.6
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
```

In the question someone asked earlier, there was no matching answer. Both answers (one in comment) do not match each other.
one says

```
profile shading language version string: 4.60 OpenGL version string
```

determines the shaders your pc has and another answer says to look at

```
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

my pc has similar specs, so I would want to know what shaders my pc supports. Also another question: does my pc have **OpenGL 4.6 or 3.1**? i see two values along two different results from `glxinfo`?

Comment: You misunderstood Pilot6's answer and comments. Pilot6 gave `OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA` as an *example* of version 3 shaders being supported. It means that OP's `shading language version string: 1.30` doesn't support shaders version 3, which is also what they said in the answer.

Comment: thanks, so i have 1.3 also,. what is my opengl version then ? do i need to look at OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8 or OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8  ?

Comment: That depends on the application. You should check what the particular game requires. See https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/8958/7655, https://askubuntu.com/a/993046/158442. If the game uses compatibility profile, then it will be stuck with `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8`. If it asks for core profile, then it will get `OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8`. I don't think anything you're likely to play on Steam uses OpenGL ES.